# How to pass multiple variables to PHP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok guys hope you can help me with this one as well. I am not to crazy knowledgeable with jQuery and AJAX and probably I am missing something very simple. I am not able to pass more than 1 variable. I have tried several different things amongst closest to what I have working is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091557/can-not-seem-to-pass-more-than-one-variable-with-jquery-to-mysql) but even that didn't work.

**jQuery**

```
$("#bodymes ul li span[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
            var weight_id = $(this).attr("id") ;
            var weightbody_mes = $(this).text() ;
            $.post( "../includes/bodymes_weight.php", { weightbodymes: weightbody_mes })  
                .done(function( data ) {   
                    $(".weightsuccess").slideDown(200); 
                    $(".weightsuccess").html("Weight Updated successfully"); 
                    if ($('.weightsuccess').length > 0) {
                        window.setTimeout(function(){
                            $('.weightsuccess').slideUp(200);
                        }, 4000);
                    }  
                    // alert( "Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        });
```

So basically If I run this it will work perfectly fine and my PHP script will process it. Notice that when I go and enable to alert me and show data loaded it shows correct info (info from `weightbodymes`) and I am able to update db. But as soon as I add another variable `{ weightbodymes: weightbody_mes, weightid: weight_id }` it won't show data loaded in alert box (if I try to show info from both variables it's working but it only submits one var only to **PHP** which is:

```
    $weightid = $_POST['weightid'];
    $weight = $_POST['weightbodymes'];

    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE body SET body_weight=? WHERE body_id='$weightid'")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('s', $weight);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../index.php?error=Registration failure: INSERT nwprogram1');
            }
    }
```

Hope you can tell me where I am making a mistake and how to correct it. 
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Add futher properties to the `data` object: `{ weightbodymes: weightbody_mes, weightid: weight_id, foo: 'bar' }`

Comment: Send something like this `{'data':{'var_1': 'value1', 'var_2' : 'value2'}}` .Then access it by `$_POST['data']['var_1'],  $_POST['data']['var_2']`

Comment: This should have what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191124/send-javascript-variable-to-php-variable

Comment: I tried first and third answer but it seems not to work. ill give it a shot couple more times. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**POST AJAX REQUEST using JS / JQUERY.**  The below is the syntax I use for all my AJAX calls.

```
var first = 'something';
var second = 'second';
var third = $("#some_input_on_your_page").val();


///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'page_that_receives_post_variables.php',
        data: {first:first, second:second, third:third},
        success: function( response ){
            alert('yay ajax is done.');
            $('#edit_box').html(response);//this is where you populate your response
        }//close succss params
    });//close ajax
///////// AJAX //////// AJAX //////////
```

**Code for the PHP page page_that_receives_post_variables.php**

```
<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$third = $_POST['third'];

echo 'now do something with the posted items.';
echo $first; //etc...
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm... this seemed like a solution but it is not working for some reason it is still passing only one variable. So for example, in a response I am only getting `weightbodymes` although I am passing both variables my data line looks like this: `data: {weightid:weight_id, weightbodymes:weightbody_mes, third:third},` (I left third element and assigned variable as well but didn't try to call it with PHP). Any other suggestion?

Comment: I made it to work with your solution. Also voted up. THANK YOU! @Stephen Carr

Comment: what was the issue?  For debugging, before you past post variables in the ajax, just alert(your_variables) so you can see if you are actually getting something.  Usually helps me.

Comment: I used alert() and gave me correct info but issue was with PHP as I have if statement and the part I posted in this question was part of "else" and in both if and else I placed the same variable while I was trying different solutions and forgot to change it so it caused the wrong records to update and whole bunch of other mess. Thank you again! @Stephen Carr