# Add Gallery Shortcode Within Wordpress Functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I add a gallery shortcode to the content in Wordpress from within my *functions.php* code?  The numbers I'm using here are hard-coded for trial but will eventually be dynamic.  Here is what I'm trying but doesn't seem to work.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse6034_the_content' );
function wpse6034_the_content( $content )
{
    $gallery_shortcode = '[gallery ids="282,283,284"]';
    $content .= '<p>Hello World!!!!</p>'.$gallery_shortcode;

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to append this to all wp posts?

Comment: no eventaully will just be a specific custom post type that will append to

Comment: the custom post types will also be password protected so the content with the gallery shouldnt show unless valid password was presented

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to append to all of one particular post type then do not do that in the functions.php file.  WordPress CODEX has an easy solution.  Just modify the POST TEMPLATE for that particular post type file and all will be done.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates   **single-{post_type}.php**

If your custom post type is **COOL_CARS** Syntax is this:

in your themes folder make a file and call the file this:

**single-COOL_CARS.php**

and now anything you edit in the template file will display for all views of that particular post type.

Comment: If i do it in the template how to I ensure that the gallery only shows when a user enters a valid password for the page/post?

Comment: I would do a simple PHP input / form on that same template.  Basically just hide your gallery and only show php form.  on password input then just show the form.  You can use AJAX like I have posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458307/how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-php-with-jquery   OR  just code a standard php web form.